How to use multer in Next js
I want to store 2 images, So I used multer to store images.
And I wrote a code that get name and add fields name at files' name. For example, when latestname is hello, the file's name is hello-thumbnail and hello-cover
import path from "path";
import multer from 'multer'
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";

const latest = await prisma.items.findFirst({
  orderBy: {
    id: 'desc',
  },
});

const latestName = latest.name.replaceAll(" ", "-")

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'D:\\nex\\uploads\\')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, latestName + '-' + file.fieldname + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
});

const upload = multer({storage : storage})

const apiRoute = createRouter({
  onError(error, req, res) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: `Sorry something Happened! ${error.message}` });
  },
  onNoMatch(req, res) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  },
});

apiRoute.use(upload.fields([{ name: 'thumbnail', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'cover', maxCount: 1 }]));

apiRoute.post((req, res) => {
  return NextResponse.json({ files: req.files });
});

export async function POST (request, ctx) {
  return apiRoute.run(request, ctx);
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

there's no error, but the file isnt saved.
directory is correct.
